# iOS 9 - Redirect to Universal Link not working

Tags: ios, redirect, ios9, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Let's assume I have two domains - example.com and ex.co

On *example.com* I've configured Universal Links for **iOS 9** and my `apple-app-site-association` file is unsigned and looks like this:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "JUSTEXAMPLE.com.example.app",
        "paths": [
          "link/example*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My application also has `com.apple.developer.associated-domains` entry - `applinks:example.com`

Everything works fine if you click `example.com/link/example?param=value` (app opens)

---

But I want to do next thing:

1. User taps ex.co/abc
2. User gets 301 header (permanent redirect) with example.com/link/example?param=value as location
3. App opens and everyone is happy

First and second execute fine, but at third one I only get blank page with little banner at the top that says something like 'Would you like to open this page in app?' and big 'OPEN' button

> **PS**: both websites are using valid HTTPS
>
> **PPS**: I can't make `apple-app-site-association` for *ex.co*, cause it's going to have many short links, that will redirect to different pages on *example.com* for different apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari on iOS (9...who knows what will happen next week!) only responds to Universal Links when the user actually takes a specific action to open the URL. That's a slight generalization, but basically a good guideline. A 301 redirect doesn't qualify, so that's why your app isn't opening up.

A workaround you could use (which we employ at [Branch.io](http://branch.io)) is to use a unique path segment for each app on the `ex.co` domain (instead of `ex.co/abc`, you'd have `ex.co/uniqueappid/abc`). Then you can trigger Universal Links based on `uniqueappid` for each app separately.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought about at first time. Looks like there's no other way :P

Comment: Hello, recently I have the same issue that redirect action doesn't open my App. So can you explain it more specifically how to solve the problem? Here 's my question: [Short URL not opened in App with Universal Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136150/short-url-not-opened-in-app-with-universal-links)