# Short URL not opened in App with Universal Links

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, deep-linking

I have set up Universal links in my iOS app, and it works with full URL like : [example.com/path/](http://example.com/path/*%22example.com/path/%22)

Recently, I want short URL like: t.cn/m , which map to [example.com/path/](http://example.com/path/*%22example.com/path/%22) , can be opened in my App directly. So I added `appplinks:t.cn` at association domain in Capabilities.

But it doesn't work. It can't be opened directly in my App.It's opened with safari and i have to click the "open" button on pull-down-banner in safari to open in my App.

It seems like short URL can't be opened directly in my App, can it?

Comment: Does `t.cn` have a valid `apple-app-site-association` file set up with your app's info?

Comment: Yes, it does. And I can GET `/t.cn/apple-app-site-association` by HTTPS with curl, postman or any other way.

Comment: Hmm...there's no restriction I am aware of about short URLs. I think we may need actual URLs and code to look at next

Comment: I got something from the device log when I installing the app: `Denying redirect 'https://t.ex.com/apple-app-site-association' -> 'https://www.example.com/apple-app-site-association'` Is it related to the problem? And by the way it's a work thing so I can't show you actual URLs and code, I' m sorry for that..

Comment: It won't work if your association file at `t.cn` is a HTTP redirect 30x . It's got to be actually there.

Comment: But t.cn is not an actual server host. How to get association file from t.cn without redirection?

Comment: @jojoT iOS does not follow redirections of any kind when checking for an AASA file. Unfortunately if you can't actually host the file on your short URL domain, you're out of luck here.

Comment: @AlexBauer OK, I see. So when I have actually host the file on short URL domain, will it open successfully in app, even if the short URL I clicked still redirects to another URL?

Comment: @jojoT at that point, the redirect will never happen. iOS will intercept the request and launch your app as soon as it sees a request for a t.co URL. It won't even make a network request.

Comment: I had a problem adding applink to the entitlement because once you add any, you need to uninstall and install again the app, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

try applink instead of appplinks

[from documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

Comment: try to describe your answer don't put links only.